# SCSS reference a selector style of another class in my own class

Tags: sass

Say I'm using a third party CSS library.  What I would like to do is reference a style that is used in their hover selector in one of my classes.

For example, there exists a 'vendor-list-item' class which has a ':hover' selector style.  I want to use THAT class's :hover style in my own hover selector.

Something like this:

```
.my-list-item {
   &:hover {
      // use .vendor-list-item:hover
   }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. 
If you compile the third party scss then you can use `@extend`

Another option is to include the class in your scss:

`.my-list-item,
.vendor-list-item {
     &:hover {
        // your style
   }
}`